# Не запускается редактор интерфейса Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Не могу открыть редактор интерфейса приложения в Android Studio. Устанавливал как обычно, с официального сайта. После каждой установки, зайдя в редактор интерфейса вижу такую картину.[image: Ошибка при открытии редактора]
Таким же образом устанавливал на другие компьютеры, однако там все работало отлично. Думал, что проблема в плохой установке sdk, однако копирование папки с sdk с другого компьютера на мой (естественно с изменением пути к sdk в самой программе) ничего не изменило. Возможно кто-то встречался с такой проблемой и знает как ее решить.

Comment: нажмите кнопку `Sync Project with Gradle files`

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, ничего не изменилось

Comment: а синхронизация успешно прошла, или с ошибкой?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, теперь выводит
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 3s

Comment: Ну, собственно, у Вас проблема только с Gradle) А вот как ее решить - понятия не имею( Попробуйте погуглить на тему вылетевшей Вам ошибки и, если не получится ничего, задавайте отдельный вопрос, либо изменяйте этот.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно очистить кеш из коммандной строки:

```
rm -r android/build ; 
rm -r android/app/src/release/res ; 
rm -r android/app/build/intermediates ; watchman watch-del-all ;  
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* ; 
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Так же как вам советуют, включите показ всех предупреждений чтобы увидеть что именно проблемное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть подобные обсуждения и вопросы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192538/deprecated-gradle-features-making-it-incompatible-with-gradle-5-0-android-studi), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361053/error-deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatibl). Так же советуют [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099048/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with) способ:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```